# IntelliJ Compass File Watcher

Tags: intellij-idea, cmd, compass-sass

I am working with IntelliJ and included an external tool.
Settings - external tools - add tool

here I added '**compass watch**' and run it.

Everything works fine, except that when compass compiled the scss it will show the psoitive result only after the next compilation.

**I would like to see when it finishes a task**, as I do in the console window.

Any idea what to change to get this working?

[image]

Here is a screenshot showing that after compass finished it does not show:

```
override ../css/app.css
```

if will show the line once a new change happends.
On an error it shows it right away.

Comment: What do you mean with psoitive result? Please describe the problem more clearly, maybe add a screenshot or so...

Comment: updated the post to show  the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the clue to the answer in this post: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5478444 It seems you should be creating a file watcher that executes the compass compile command rather than the watcher command. Note that there is an option to choose "Show Console" (see screen print below) as 'Always', 'Never', or 'Error'.

Here's what I did to setup compass for my project:

1) at the command line in the project root directory:

```
% run compass install compass
directory sass/
directory stylesheets/
   create sass/screen.scss
   create sass/print.scss
   create sass/ie.scss
   create stylesheets/screen.css
   create stylesheets/print.css
   create stylesheets/ie.css
```

2) then I went into the project and moved all the sass files to sass/ and all the css files to css/

3) then I created a new File Watcher per the screen shot[image: File Watcher]

**For Windows**

The settings from the screen shot didn't work exactly for me on Windows.  Here's my settings that did work:

```
Program:           C:\Ruby200\bin\compass.bat
Arguments:         compile $FileParentDir$ --sass-dir sass --css-dir stylesheets
Working Directory: $FileParentDir$
Output paths:      <blank>
```

Comment: +1, worked for me with some minor changes.  I noted my windows settings above.

Answer (score 0):

For others who also has issues with this. I ended up using this folder structure in a Grails project in Intellij Idea 13.1.3 Ultimate:

```
- grails-app
  ...
  ...
- web-app
  - css
  - sass
  - and-so-on
  config.rb
```

With the config.rb as:

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"
```

And a [filewatcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uIZG.png) with these settings:

```
Program:           C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin\compass.bat
Arguments:         compile
Working Directory: $FileParentDir$
Output paths:      C:/path-to-project-folder
```